# MIME handler for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, types, mime, handler, npapi

I want to have an equivalent of NPAPI plugin for Firefox (or just any other sane browser).
Generally I need IE to start my own program in response to object tag and let it
draw the content itself.

Where do I start?

I tried to look it up on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902517.aspx

but could not find anything suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent plugin mechanism for IE is an ActiveX [content extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This is cumbersome to do by hand, so do it using support from MFC or ATL.

Here are two tutorials that turned up on a web search (there are many more out there):

- [ATL based](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/ScriptableActiveX.aspx)
- [MFC based](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/CompleteActiveX.aspx)

If you need to support both NPAPI and ActiveX, take a look at our [FireBreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/) framework. Its goal is to write the plugin only once and let the framework take care of ActiveX and NPAPI support.
At the very least you could use the sources as a reference if needed - use `src/ActiveXPlugin` and specifically `FBControl` and `JSAPI_IDispatchEx` as a starting point.